# printf in bash does not output hole string and dose not do the replace

Tags: bash, shell, printf

I have long string

```
MESSAGE='<style>body{font-family:Arial,sans-serif;margin:0;padding:20px}h1{color:#333}p{margin-bottom:10px}.points{margin-bottom:20px}.point{margin-bottom:10px;list-style-type:disc}</style><p>Bonjour,</p><p>La plateforme INTERACTIVE FACTORY %s va entrer en maintenance.</p><p>Changement(s) :</p><ul>%s<div class="points"></ul></div><p>Laplateforme sera indisponible durant l"opération.</p>'
```

I want the place holders **"%s"** to be replaced with two other vars

```
var1="TOTO"
var2='<li class="points">5.2</li><li class="points">foo=verify-full</li>'
```

I did this but it's not working

```
newvar=printf $MESSAGE $var1 $var2
```

output

```
<style>body{font-family:Arial,sans-serif;margin:0;padding:20px}h1{color:#333}p{margin-bottom:10px}.points{margin-bottom:20px}.point{margin-bottom:10px;list-style-type:disc}</style><p>Bonjour,</p><p>La
```

why it's not working and why I get such output ?

Comment: Check your script with shellcheck

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `printf -v newvar "$MESSAGE" "$var1" "$var2"` -- mind the quotes. Or `newvar=$(printf "$MESSAGE" "$var1" "$var2")`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that's correct you want to put that as response ?

Comment: The question is already closed so answers can't be added -- but everything you need to come up with those lines yourself is given in the two linked duplicates.